# How to sync .ssh folder from Windows to WSL1 correctly?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to sync `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` and `~/.ssh` in WSL1 correctly, but I don't know how to achieve that. I tried to use `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/ .ssh`, and it does create a symbolic link as I expect. But ssh don't like permission of files in `~/.ssh` (0777), and `chmod` doesn't work here. (Maybe because they are files under NTFS.)

Is there a way to mock the permission so that ssh could accept it? Or is there are a better way to do this than symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

If a symlink approach is not possible, you might want to synchronize on demand, meaning manually copy, your keys from your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder to the one representing `$HOME` for WSL1.
See "[What is the home directory on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)", For example [`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\lxss`](https://superuser.com/a/1340510/141).

This might be easier to do with [WSL2 though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions).